# Failed conversion the IF/Else condition to Ramda Cond

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, ramda.js, angularjs-e2e

Working on an E2E using Ramda. I'm not getting how to convert a simple IF condition using Ramda Cond.

Code using If :

```
if (constraint == 'required') {
  // then only do something
  await waitForElementToBeClickable(constraintElement);
  await constraint.click();
}
```

I don't want the else because I want the action to happen only if the constraint is present.

I've done this so far using constraint but it's not working :

```
await waitForElementToBeClickable(cond([
  [equals('required'), always(constraintElement)],
])(constraint), this.browser);

const constraintCheck = cond([
  [equals('required'), () => constraintElement.click()],
]);
await constraintCheck(constraint);
```

In some cases, I do not want to pass the constraint. Then the Condition should not execute at all. But it is always getting executed and throwing the error : Cannot read property 'isPresent' of Undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps there's some confusion here (beyond what customcommander rightly points out about the type of `constraint`.)

One of the features Ramda tries to offer is to allow us to program with *expressions* rather than *statements*.  Especially concerning are control-flow statements.  But a statement that looks like this:

```
let foo
if (condition) {
  foo = 'bar'
} else {
  foo = 'baz'
}
```

already has a standard expression form:

```
const foo = condition ? 'bar' : 'baz'
```

Ramda does not really try to offer an alternative to this.  But there is another way we might try to use `if`:

```
let foo
if (test(val)) {
  foo = bar(val)
} else {
  foo = baz(val)
}
```

Here, when working with functions, Ramda offers a convenient shorthand:

```
const getFoo = ifElse(test, bar, baz)
// ... later
const foo = getFoo(val)
```

> (And if you just want to return `val` in the case the test fails, you can use the shorthand:
>
> ```
>    const foo = when(test, bar)
> ```
>
> Or if you want `val` when the test succeeds, you can do
>
> ```
>    const foo = unless(test, baz)
> ```
>
> )

While it might be slightly more expressive to turn the code into

```
const foo = ifElse(test, bar, baz)(val)
```

That's not the main point.  The rationale for `ifElse` is to use it in creating the reusable function `ifElse(test, bar, baz)`.  (`cond` is just the same, just offering a sequence of condition-consequent pairs instead of one `if` and one `else`.)

Note one important feature to this: the test function, the function to run if it's true, and the one to run if it's false all have the same signature.  If one of them takes three parameters, then they all should accept three parameters.  And while the test should return a boolean, the other two can have any return type, but each should have the same return type as the other.

So one can use a thunk, as you try with `() => constraintElement.click()`, it is mostly a misuse of the Ramda feature.  It probably gains you nothing in your code.

---

It's still not clear what you're trying to do with the conversion from an `if` statement to `ifElse` or `cond`.  Please feel free to add an update to your question explaining more fully what you're trying to do, and what problem you're trying to solve with this conversion, someone will probably be able to offer some help.  But make sure you clarify what `constraint` and `constraintElement` are and what `waitForElementToBeClickable` resolves to.  Right now it's fairly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your example, it seems that you use `constraint` both as a string and an object which may cause unnecessary confusion. I know you can implement a `toString()` method on an object but I'm not sure if that always plays nicely when you integrate with external libraries

```js
const obj = {
  toString: () => 'burrito',
  order: () => ''
};

obj + '' === 'burrito' // true
obj === 'burrito' // false

equals('burrito', obj + '') // true
equals('burrito', obj) // false
```

I would suggest that you convert your object into a string before you make the check:

```js
const check = pipe(
  toString,
  equals('burrito')
);

check(obj); // true
```

Then if you don't need an "else" branch, you could consider using [when](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#when).

```js
const execute = when(check, invoker(0, 'order'))
execute(obj); // ""
execute({}); // {}
```

Comment: I did not get the solution. But I've updated my question though. I'm using the constraint only as a string.

Comment: It's just that in your first code sample, you do `constraint == 'required'` then a few lines later you do `await constraint.click();`. That's what I mean by handling a variable both as a string and an object. Do you a complete reproducible example to share?

Comment: That would be great. I tried many times but failed. I just want to execute a block of code if there is something in the string i.e (constraint == 'required'). If its empty just do nothing. R.Cond is really messing up with my brain.

Comment: You don't need `R.cond` if you only need one branch. Use `R.when` instead.

Comment: Oh... let me have a look at it then.